# Adding New Rule Email Using Applescript

Tags: applescript

I want to create an Apple script that creates a new rule in the Mac mail app where if I receive an email, and the title of the email is "test", I want an Apple script to start.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set newRule to make new rule at end of rules with properties {name:"test rule", Run applescript:"test.scpt"}
    tell newRule
       make new rule condition at end of rule conditions with properties {rule type:message content, qualifier:does contain value, expression:"test"}
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the second property in the `make` line is `run script`.

Try this

```
set applicationScriptsFolder to (path to library folder from user domain as text) & "Application Scripts:com.apple.mail:"
tell application "Mail"
    set newRule to make new rule with properties {name:"test rule", run script:alias (applicationScriptsFolder & "test.scpt")}
    tell newRule
        make new rule condition at end of rule conditions with properties {rule type:message content, qualifier:does contain value, expression:"test"}
    end tell
end tell
```

**Edit:**
It seems that the `run script` parameter needs the full path to the script.

Strangely the script is not displayed in Mail Preferences > Rules but the property can be read with AppleScript.

Comment: I updated the answer: The script to create a rule is not required to be located in the Application Scripts folder, the scripts to be triggered by the rule are.

Comment: I didn't get error, and it did make rule, but script isn't selected.

Comment: It did make rule, but script isn't selected.

Comment: Yes, that's what the last paragraph in my answer means, but please try the rule, it might work

Comment: my code is   :                                                                                                         tell application "Mail"
 set newRule to make new rule at end of rules with properties {name:"test rule", run script:"/Users/student/Library/Application Scripts/com.apple.mail/test.scpt"}
 tell newRule
  make new rule condition at end of rule conditions with properties {rule type:message content, qualifier:does contain value, expression:"test"}
 end tell
end tell